# Unable get resource group using Azure CLI - Get-AzureRmResourceGroup command

Tags: azure-resource-manager

When I am trying to run `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` powershell command, I am getting an error like this.

[image: Error - Get-AzureRmResourceGroup]

I am able to execute `Connect-AzAccount` command and I am able to login to my subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use compatibility mode with cmdlet [Enable-AzureRmAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-1.1.0) to enable **AzureRm** prefix aliases for **Az** modules.

By Default, This cmdlet will enable AzureRM aliases in the Az module for the current PowerShell session. You also could add `Scope` parameter like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/announcing-az-module.md#migrating-from-azurerm).

```
Enable-AzureRmAlias [-Module <string>] [-Scope Process | CurrentUser | LocalMachine]
```

[image]

Ref: [Azure PowerShell – Cross-platform “Az” module replacing “AzureRM”](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/)

Comment: @4c74356b41 I only have az module, no azurerm module on my side. So I need to enable azurermalise to use `get-azurermresourcegroup` command.

Comment: If you `Disable-AzureRmAlias` then try?

Comment: I just could produce this issue, I only install Az module, no AzureRM module on my side. What do you mean?

Comment: `get-azurermresourcegroup | sort location,resourcegroup | ft
get-azurermresourcegroup : The term 'get-azurermresourcegroup' is not recognized`

Comment: Not sure, I just can see the above issue, not the same as you. az module version is 1.1.0

Comment: i've got the same version. what are you using windows 7 or something

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise desktop, do you try get-azurermxxxx other cmdlets?

Comment: all of them return cmdlet is not recognized **like they should**